# Assign value to array in for loop

Tags: php

I know init php array method is

```
$a=array("星期日","星期一","星期二","星期三","星期四","星期五","星期六");
```

but i must assign in two dim array, such data is

```
 [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["menu_name"]=> string(12) "小吃菜單" ["button_pic_save_path"]=> string(40) "/images/left_button/menu/normal_menu.gif" ["cover_button_pic_save_path"]=> string(46) "/images/left_button/menu/normal_menu_cover.gif" ["order_number"]=> string(1) "0" ["modify_time"]=> string(19) "2013-04-07 09:37:43" } } 
 [1]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["menu_name"]=> string(12) "小吃菜單" ["button_pic_save_path"]=> string(40) "/images/left_button/menu/normal_menu.gif" ["cover_button_pic_save_path"]=> string(46) "/images/left_button/menu/normal_menu_cover.gif" ["order_number"]=> string(1) "0" ["modify_time"]=> string(19) "2013-04-07 09:37:43" } }
```

now my Implement code as follow..

```
$query_menu_data = select_sql(QUERY_MENU_SQL_STR);

if(count($query_menu_data) >= 1)
{
    $ary_menu[count($query_menu_data)];

    for($loop_i = 0; $loop_i < count($query_menu_data); $loop_i++)
    {
        for($loop_j = 0; $loop_j < count($ARY_MENU_FIELD); $loop_j++)
        {
            // hash key
            /*
            $ary_menu[$loop_i] = array( 
                $ARY_MENU_FIELD[$loop_j] =>  $query_menu_data[$loop_i][$loop_j]
            );
            */
            $ary_menu[$loop_i] = array( 
                $ARY_MENU_FIELD[$loop_j] =>  $query_menu_data[$loop_i][$loop_j]
            );
        }   // end loop j
    } // end loop i
}
```

the result of array always save the last data, what method can I solve it.

Thank to every body, the solve method is in comment.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want your array to look like and what you are actually getting? Also including non alphabet (English) characters may put some people off...

Comment: @Floris Those Chinese words mean Sunday to Saturday.

Comment: @antony - thanks for letting me know. I still think it may make many people not finish reading the question and that was the (less important, secondary) point of my comment.

Comment: @Floris You are right. The actual problem here is that it is hard to understand what the OP means in his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the menu entry. after doing that you need to fill each menu field for this menu.

code:

```
for($loop_i = 0; $loop_i < count($query_menu_data); $loop_i++)
{
    $ary_menu[$loop_i] = array();
    for($loop_j = 0; $loop_j < count($ARY_MENU_FIELD); $loop_j++)
    {
        // hash key
        /*
        $ary_menu[$loop_i] = array( 
            $ARY_MENU_FIELD[$loop_j] =>  $query_menu_data[$loop_i][$loop_j]
        );
        */
        $ary_menu[$loop_i][$ARY_MENU_FIELD[$loop_j]] = $query_menu_data[$loop_i][$loop_j];
    }   // end loop j
} // end loop i
```

i cant verify, if `$query_menu_data` has the correct data structure, but from your problem description, there should be no problem there.

Comment: thank to every body, specific to scones,
the code

     $ary_menu[$loop_i][$ARY_MENU_FIELD[$loop_j]] = $query_menu_data[$loop_i][$loop_j];

will work for my target.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your inner loop (`loop_j`) may never execute since you did not have $ARY_MENU_FIELD defined before you first execute it (and it is created/modified inside that loop). Is there other code you are not showing?

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter problems with arrays only containing the "last" bit of data after a traversal/loop, you should assume that you are making an overwriting error somewhere.

Looking at your loop, the assignment comes in the second loop, with...

`$ary_menu[$loop_i] = array(...`

The `=` equals sign above should be the clue your looking for. You're assigning the index of `$loop_i` in the array `$ary_menu` over and over, every time the inner `$loop_j` for-loop runs. This is where the reassignment occurs.

Since I do not know exactly what you're trying to look for in a final array, I can only give an assumption on a solution. This might be doing something like...

`$ary_menu[$loop_i][] = array(....)`

What this will do is essentially make `$ary_menu[$loop_i]` an array of its own, appending the new value in each loop iteration. This will solve the problem of overwriting. But again, I'm not sure if that's what you're looking to do.